# Insert into table b from table a where not exist in b

Tags: mysql

Why doesn't this seem to work in MySQL? When I run the select, it returns records but the records are in both tables. It should only return records from stg that are not in vista_hospital_hap3. I want to insert to vista_hospital_hap3 from stg table where it isn't in the vista_hospital_hap3.

So basically trying to insert new records.

```
INSERT INTO VISTA_HOSPITAL_HAP3
 ( DESCRIPTION,
   LOCATION_PLACE,
   LOCATION_AREA,
   LOCATION_CD,
   SOURCE_ADMISSION_ID,
   SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME,
   SOURCE_TABLE_NAME,
   SOURCE_TABLE_KEY,
   TS,
   VALUE,
   VALUE_TEXT,
   VALUE_DATE,
   EXTRACT_DATE,
   LOAD_DATE,
   SOURCE_PATIENT_ID,
   HASH_KEY,
   RGI_LOAD_DATE,
   RGI_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
   SUBIEN)
 SELECT 
   stg.DESCRIPTION,
   stg.LOCATION_PLACE,
   stg.LOCATION_AREA,
   stg.LOCATION_CD,
   stg.SOURCE_ADMISSION_ID,
   stg.SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME,
   stg.SOURCE_TABLE_NAME,
   stg.SOURCE_TABLE_KEY,
   stg.TS,
   stg.VALUE,
   stg.VALUE_TEXT,
   stg.VALUE_DATE,
   stg.EXTRACT_DATE,
   stg.LOAD_DATE,
   stg.SOURCE_PATIENT_ID,
   stg.HASH_KEY,
   stg.RGI_LOAD_DATE,
   stg.RGI_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
   stg.SUBIEN

  FROM STG_VISTA_HOSPITAL_HAP3 stg  LEFT OUTER JOIN VISTA_HOSPITAL_HAP3 trg 
                                    ON  stg.DESCRIPTION = trg.DESCRIPTION         
                          AND stg.SOURCE_ADMISSION_ID = trg.SOURCE_ADMISSION_ID
                          AND stg.SOURCE_TABLE_NAME   = trg.SOURCE_TABLE_NAME
                          AND stg.SUBIEN              = trg.SUBIEN 
 WHERE 
       trg.DESCRIPTION         IS NULL
 AND   trg.SOURCE_ADMISSION_ID IS NULL
 AND   trg.SOURCE_TABLE_NAME   IS NULL
 AND   trg.SUBIEN              IS NULL;
```

Comment: Have your table a primary key?

Comment: Insert doesn't allow Where condition in MySQL

Comment: This would work in SQLServer. So how do I do it in MySQL?